# How to NOT save both parent and child record when associated child record is not valid in rails 3.1.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-attributes

In our rails 3.1.4 app, there are user (parent) and user_levels (child) models.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :login, :password, :user_levels_attributes, :as => :role_new
  has_many :user_levels
  ccepts_nested_attributes_for :user_levels, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |a| a['position'].blank? }
  validates_associated :user_levels
end

class UserLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :position
end
```

The position column in user_level has to be filled. If it is not, both user and user_levels should NOT be saved. The problem with the above is that it always causes error of "position can't be blank" even there is a position value in the params.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"tester ceo",
 "login"=>"testceo",
 "update_password_checkbox"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "user_levels_attributes"=>{"1339886115748"=>{"position"=>"ceo"}}},
 "commit"=>"Save"}
```

After deleting user_levels_attribues, the model saves user into users table no matter what kind of user_levels is filled int. We did extensive online search and haven't found a solution yet. For example, if validates_presence_of :user_levels is added to the user model, then none of the user levels can be saved or updated, even with a valid position.

Any suggestion about how to implement the orchestrated saving/updating of two associated models? Thanks so much.

UPDATE:
_user_level.html.erb:

```
<div class="fields">
  <%= f.input :position, :collection => return_position, :prompt => "Choose position", 
                      :label => false, :include_blank => true, :selected => i_id %>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</div>
```

_form_new.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, :label => 'name：' %>
  <%= f.input :login, :label => 'login：', :hint => '6 digits ' %>
  <%= f.input :password, :label => 'password：', :hint => '6digits', :input_html => {:id => 'new_user_password'} %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => 'confirmation：' %>  
  <%= f.input :user_type, :label => 'user type：', :collection => return_user_type, :include_blank => true %>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;position：
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Choose position", f, :user_levels %></p>

  <p><%= f.button :submit, 'Save' %></p>
<% end %>
```

Here is the method to add position field:

```
  #add user position in system user creation
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render :partial => association.to_s, :locals => {:f => builder, :i_id => 0} 
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{j fields}\")")
  end
```

JS file:

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

Comment: What do your tests look like in this case?

Comment: We use rspec. Test case failed with the same error which is "position can't be blank".

Comment: Try inspecting the page in firebug before you submit it, to see if there's an extra user_levels partial on the page.

Comment: @Charles, only find one user_level partial on the form if "add position" is clicked one time. If user_levels_attributes is removed from the attr_accessible user model, the user can be saved without "User level can't be blank" error. Not sure why those two are linked together.

Comment: It sounds like something, somewhere in your code (maybe in the User model?) is creating an extra UserLevel, but I don't see any issues with what you've posted.

Comment: The code was migrated from another running app. We just notice the the code will save user even with a blank user level. The may create a user without a position and this is not what it should be. We don't want user to be saved with a blank user_level input. Another change we did is to introduce the attr_accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `:reject_if` and change `validates_associated :user_levels` to `validates_presence_of :user_levels`.

Comment: Still same error:"User levels can't be blank", with position as 'ceo' in params. Thanks.

Comment: @user938363 I notice that the id in the "user_levels_attributes" hash looks pretty high...are you doing something w/ AJAX to dynamically add user_levels to the form?  If so, check that the user_levels template is removed from the form.

Comment: Yes, it is dynamically added user_level with a partial form (field_for). I don't quite understand what you meant for "user_levels template is removed from the form". If user_level partial form is removed from the user input form, there is no way we can enter the data for user_level.

Comment: @user938363 Can you edit your question to include your user form partial and the javascript you're using to add user_levels to the form?

Comment: just added more code in question. They may be too much and make the question hard to read. Thanks.

Comment: The solution works after adding attr_accessible :position in user_level model and other fields that needs to be mass assigned in user model. All those fields are mass assignment protected by a before_filter :require_admin in user controller.

Comment: Only problem is that it allows the last (only one) user position to be deleted, because the system checks validates_presence_of :user_levels BEFORE deleting. Any idea to cover this loop hole? Thanks.

Comment: The problem could be solved by providing first position selection on form without "remove" button. There is always ONE position on form.